# SQL Join Commands

Tags: sql, sql-server

So im trying to execute a SQL join command for two tables, but am getting an output im not looking for.

```
> SELECT        owners_table.ownerID, tenant_table.tenantID, tenant_table.apt_num, tenant_table.last_name, owners_table.last_name AS owner_last, tenant_table.phone, 
                         owners_table.phone AS owner_phone
FROM            owners_table INNER JOIN
                         tenant_table ON tenant_table.apt_status = 'ARCHIVED' AND owners_table.owner_status = 'ARCHIVED'
ORDER BY owners_table.apt_num"
```

In the output, it displays 5 records of 'stralman', but there is only one. I understand the join clause is trying to match it up but is there a way to display only 1 stralman for the 5 corresponding records?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfbWW.png

table structure: 
1) tenant table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUxMH.png
2) owners table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqoKx.png

Comment: It's because your `tenantID` has multiple, different values for that name.

Comment: Did you try using Left Join?

Comment: Can we see your table structure?

Comment: Table structures added to original post

Answer (score 5):

You don't establish a relationship between the two tables in the join. You need at least one condition in your ON clause to have an expression from the first table on one side of the condition and an expression from the other table on the other side of the condition, like this:

```
FROM owners_table 
INNER JOIN tenant_table ON tenant_table.apt_num = owners_table.apt_num
```

Note that this may not be the right join condition for your needs, because we can't know from the given information what other columns you might need to relate an owner to a tenant.

Comment: So the condition of 'tenant_table.apt_status = 'ARCHIVED' AND owners_table.owner_status = 'ARCHIVED' is not a valid relationship condition?

Comment: It doesn't relate anything between the two tables. You are just saying get records from each table where the status is 'ARCHIVED' and then join all of them together into a Cartesian product. A relationship condition needs to specify some value from tenant_table equal to some value of owners_table as the example from Joel states.

Comment: Okay, that makes alot of sense.So how do you suggest i check for archived records once i make the relationship?

Comment: That condition can go in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

looks like (from ther schema) the join should be on OwnerId, so your query becomes:

```
SELECT owners_table.ownerID, 
    tenant_table.tenantID, 
    tenant_table.apt_num, 
    tenant_table.last_name, 
    owners_table.last_name AS owner_last, 
    tenant_table.phone, 
    owners_table.phone AS owner_phone
FROM owners_table 
INNER 
JOIN tenant_table 
    ON tenant_table.OwnerID = owners_table.OwnerID
WHERE tenant_table.apt_status = 'ARCHIVED' 
AND owners_table.owner_status = 'ARCHIVED'
ORDER BY owners_table.apt_num
```

Answer (score 0):

if everything about the query is correct except for number of records returned, try adding DISTINCT after the word SELECT

Comment: if you se the image example DISTINCT will not work because each row is technically unique